# Groovy if statament

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

I'm new to Groovy and came to Groovy and grails from Java.

I cannot explain  this:

```
boolean boolVar = false
if (boolVar) {
  print "ok"
}
```

but code execution run inside "if" block, nut boolVar is false
debugger session screenshot

[image]

Comment: I came across the same problem once, didnt have time to investigate, i have done a `boolVar == true`

Comment: the same, it doesn't help

Comment: If the `== true` didn't work, it's weird . If you are in Grails, try restarting the server.

Comment: Below you can read what problem in Grails, but here it's just a groovy script file to test this issue

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Groovy 1.7.8 or 2.4.3. What version are you using?

Comment: is it actually printing "ok" or is this just about a confused debugger?

Comment: No, it's just a debugger error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the screenshot is a bit wrong as you have nothing after the condition so intelliJ highlight this line but **it does not execute it**, it seems it goes to the block but it does not print the ok, can you show the result of the run window ?

for example add this to your code

```
boolean boolVar = false
def output = "I start here"
if (boolVar) {
    output += "\noops in loop"
    println "ok"
}
print output
```

only `I start here` is being printed

Comment: Yes, but how to explain the behaviour of IDE? Maybe due to internal transformations to bytecode, but  I think IDE debugger must follow original code that user has entered

Comment: It is just a matter of how intelliJ shows the blue line, after executing a statement, the blue line automatically goes to the next statement to execute, in this case there is none (because there is nothing after the if block and the code inside the block should not execute) so you can consider a bug from intelliJ but clearly the statement is not executed and does not print anything, groovy condition is working as expected

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get it by 100%, did you try this?

```
boolean boolVar = false
if (!boolVar) {
println "ok"
}
```

if(boolVar) and if(boolVar == true) is the same

Answer (score 0):

1.) Remove all breakpoints from your project (*Run->View Breakpoints* and delete all breakpoints)
2.) Clean the target directory.
3.) Add a new breakpoint at the "print" statement and check if it works now.